# Perl constant array

Tags: perl

```
use constant {
    COLUMNS => qw/ TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 /,
}
```

Can I store an array using the constant package in Perl?

Whenever I go on to try to use the array like `my @attr = (COLUMNS);`, it does not contain the values.

Comment: [Use named constants, but don't use constant.](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/perl/0596001738/4dot-values-and-expressions/constants)

Comment: Even after modifying your code as shown by the answers below, the result will not be very useful as you can still modify the contents of a constant reference: `perl -e 'use constant C => [1,2,3]; C->[1] = 5; print C->[1]. "\n";'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `+` to signify that it's a contant.

```
use constant {
  COLUMNS => [qw/ TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 /],
};

print @{+COLUMNS};
```

The `+` is a hint to the interpreter that the constant is actually a constant, and not a bare word. See [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21173602/588306) for more details.

Comment: It is a hint to interpreter, to make disambiguation. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/21173602/223226

Answer (score 12):

Or remove the curly braces as the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html) show :-

```
  1 use strict;
  2 use constant COLUMNS => qw/ TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 /;
  3 
  4 my @attr = (COLUMNS);
  5 print @attr;
```

which gives :-

```
 % perl test.pl
TEST1TEST2TEST3
```

Your code actually defines two constants COLUMNS and TEST2 :-

```
use strict;
use constant { COLUMNS => qw/ TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 /, };

my @attr = (COLUMNS);
print @attr;
print TEST2
```

and gives :-

```
% perl test.pl
TEST1TEST3
```

Comment: +1  The use of braces (a hashref) imposes an interpretation the OP doesn't want.