# What does a plus sign mean in a hash?

Tags: perl, constants

I have the following piece of Perl code, but I can't understand what its doing.

```
use constant ANIMAL => 'rabbit'; 
if ($self->{+ANIMAL}) {
    # Do something here
}
```

What does the `+` sign before the constant `ANIMAL` mean?

Comment: "What does a plus sign in perl map mean?" I don't see `map` in your code.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot some people call a hash a map, so maybe that is what Nosrettap meant?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [`perldoc constant`](http://metacpan.org/pod/constant):

> You can get into trouble if you use constants in a context which automatically quotes barewords (as is true for any subroutine call). For example, you can't say `$hash{CONSTANT}` because `CONSTANT` will be interpreted as a string. Use `$hash{CONSTANT()}` or `$hash{+CONSTANT}` to prevent the bareword quoting mechanism from kicking in. Similarly, since the `=>` operator quotes a bareword immediately to its left, you have to say `CONSTANT() => 'value'` (or simply use a comma in place of the big arrow) instead of `CONSTANT => 'value'`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `+` is the unary plus operator, which simply yields the value of its operand. It's basically a no-op, used here to tweak the syntax.

Answer (score 8):

Building upon [Denis Ibaev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1186729/denis-ibaev)'s response, [B::Deparse](http://search.cpan.org/~dom/perl-5.12.5/dist/B-Deparse/Deparse.pm) can show how the code is parsed with and without using the `+`:

`perl -MO=Deparse,-p script.pl`

With `+`:

```
use constant ('ANIMAL', 'rabbit');
if ($$self{+'rabbit'}) {
    ();
}
script.pl syntax OK
```

Without `+`:

```
use constant ('ANIMAL', 'rabbit');
if ($$self{'ANIMAL'}) {
    ();
}
script.pl syntax OK
```

Note that the `+` invokes using the `constant` where the bareword `ANIMAL` is used without the `+`.