# Perl : How to use constant tag value as key of associative array in?

Tags: perl

How to use constant tag value as key of hash in perl ?

The output of below code is "CONST_TAG". I want the output to be "MyKey".

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use constant CONST_TAG => 'MyKey';

my $rec = {};
$rec->{CONST_TAG} = "testName";
printf "%s\n", keys(%{$rec});
```

Comment: See [What does a plus sign mean in a hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173481/what-does-a-plus-sign-mean-in-a-hash/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$rec->{CONST_TAG()} = "testName";
```

---

This is because barewords (such as `CONST_TAG`) in hash accesses are converted to strings. Thus, `CONST_TAG` becomes the string `'CONST_TAG'`.

The statement

```
use constant NAME => VALUE;
```

creates a subroutine with an empty prototype:

```
sub NAME () { VALUE }
```

By explicitly calling it, you avoid the automatic quoting of barewords inside hash accesses.

Comment: You could improve the quality of your answer by adding some explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Besides calling the sub (a constant is just a sub after all) explicitly by putting the parenthesis on it like user49740 said in his answer, you can also add a `+` sign in front of the [bareword](http://perlmaven.com/barewords-in-perl). That will turn off the automatic quoting of barewords inside hash access curlies.

```
$res->{+CONST_TAG} = "testName";
```

See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/432133/1331451) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/404822/1331451) also.